# Adjust the screen brightness automatically Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04

I am using currently Ubuntu 22.04, and I can no more find the option to adjust automatically the screen brightness, unlike previous versions of Ubuntu.

I installed all the updates until today's date.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean "adjust automatically?" by using the ambient light sensor on a laptop or something?